# Different navbar text color for different sector of page

Tags: html, css

Right now my navbar text is white on every page. The idea is to make the navbar text on second and fourth page in black color to see it. Page background colors are different. In my case pages are just div sectors, not separate htmls. What should I put in CSS to do this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*NAVBAR START*/

#nav li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
}

li a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}


/*NAVBAR END*/

.center {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 130px 0 0 0;
}

#page1,
#page3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 800px;
}

#page2,
#page4 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 800px;
}

#font-page1 {
  color: white;
}

#font-page2 {
  color: black;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  /*NAVBAR START*/
  #nav li {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
  }
  /*NAVBAR END*/
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#page1">PAGE1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page2">PAGE2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page3">PAGE3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page4">PAGE4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="page1">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page1">Morbi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page2">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page2">Morbi molest.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page3">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page1">Morbi</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page4">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page2">Morbi molest.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now my navbar text is white on every page. The idea is to make the navbar text on second and fourth page in black color to see it. Page background colors are different. In my case pages are just div sectors, not separate htmls. What should I put in CSS to do this?

Comment: It would help to have different class names or ids in the body element and then base the navbar color off of those classes. Otherwise you can't really tell which page you're on.

Comment: Do you have unique html files for every single page?

Comment: @pavger, but I already have different id's for every page. (id="page1" etc.) or do you mean something else?

Comment: @LeventeOtta No, I don't have.

Comment: That is what I meant, as long as the class is on the body or html element. So if you want page 1 to have a black navbar do this in css: `#page1 #nav { background-color: black; }`

Comment: @pavger, I've tried. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not necessarily need a plugin. Something like this should work:

```js
var top1 = $('#page1').offset().top;
var top2 = $('#page2').offset().top;
var top3 = $('#page3').offset().top;
var top4 = $('#page4').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (scrollPos >= top1 && scrollPos < top2) {
    $('#nav a').css('color', '#fff');
  } else if (scrollPos >= top2 && scrollPos < top3) {
    $('#nav a').css('color', '#000');
  } else if (scrollPos >= top3 && scrollPos < top4) {
    $('#nav a').css('color', '#fff');
  } else if (scrollPos >= top4) {
    $('#nav a').css('color', '#000');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*NAVBAR START*/

#nav li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
}

li a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}


/*NAVBAR END*/

.center {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 130px 0 0 0;
}

#page1,
#page3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 800px;
}

#page2,
#page4 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 800px;
}

#font-page1 {
  color: white;
}

#font-page2 {
  color: black;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  /*NAVBAR START*/
  #nav li {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
  }
}


/*NAVBAR END*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#page1">PAGE1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page2">PAGE2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page3">PAGE3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page4">PAGE4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="page1">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page1">Morbi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page2">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page2">Morbi molest.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page3">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page1">Morbi</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page4">
  <div class="center">
    <p id="font-page2">Morbi molest.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied your special code in the head of my html and surrounded with <script>...</script>. I also added a link to ajax before a code but It doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The html element was loading before the JavaScript so top was undefined. You need to put the jQuery code in a document.ready function. Put this before the first line of JavaScript: `$(document).ready(function () {` and this after the last line of JavaScript: `});`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, because css can not handle scrolling. You should use javascript.

Comment: But right now I don't use any javascript codes for scrolling. Do I still need to use javascript?

Comment: I think yes, because js is the most painless solution for `check element is on screen`. I recommend to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and a [plugin](https://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/).